# Unable to access nested array object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I am trying to display the product array information such as `name` image `url` from the `categories` object. Here is the structure of the object.

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "__typename": "Category",
      "categoryId": "aeb50ed6-580d-a065-383a-e3932fbec6a1",
      "name": "Electronics",
      "products": [
        {
          "__typename": "Product",
          "productId": "f1ea5d7a-c26e-d850-52b5-9ac4c19668f2",
          "name": "Small Soft Salad",
          "price": 841,
          "discount": 23,
          "unitsSold": 5,
          "images": [
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/511dBXGmAtL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/71MIvKxxSvL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81loLb-NTYL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81goU9h-jnL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/61pUul1oDlL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "__typename": "Product",
          "productId": "b2d38cf6-b8c7-6449-e13a-8ef3bdd12dd0",
          "name": "Tasty Plastic Pants",
          "price": 250,
          "discount": 44,
          "unitsSold": 2,
          "images": [
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/511dBXGmAtL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/61pUul1oDlL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/61S0sV1a57L._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81WnMBnbWSL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/71266hQjO8L._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "__typename": "Product",
          "productId": "4ac166a1-9636-d299-e7a6-13a9c451582c",
          "name": "Fantastic Plastic Pizza",
          "price": 192,
          "discount": 26,
          "unitsSold": 18,
          "images": [
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81WFWi9sKlL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/71ZE0VUjkSL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81WnMBnbWSL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/61S0sV1a57L._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81zbIt0p5qL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "__typename": "Product",
          "productId": "c9f91096-4e77-30e8-fbde-c14f97d25d77",
          "name": "Tasty Rubber Car",
          "price": 611,
          "discount": 4,
          "unitsSold": 27,
          "images": [
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81WFWi9sKlL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/71WCgLmDx7L._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/71nJ48O6aFL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81goU9h-jnL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/71MIvKxxSvL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            }
          ]
        },
```

Here is what I tried to access the `name` and image `url` of the product array.

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import useStore from "./store/store";

const PRODUCT_QUERY = gql`
  {
    categories {
      categoryId
      name
      products {
        productId
        name
        price
        discount
        unitsSold
        images {
          url
        }
      }
      subCategories {
        name
        subCategoryId
        categoryId
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Hero = () => {
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);
  const furniture = useStore((state) => state.furnitures);
  const electronic = useStore((state) => state.electronics);
  const accessorie = useStore((state) => state.accessories);
  const vehicle = useStore((state) => state.vehicles);
  const fashion = useStore((state) => state.fashions);
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(PRODUCT_QUERY);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex space-x-10 justify-center items-center">
        <div onClick={furniture}>Furnitires</div>
        <div onClick={electronic}>Electroinics</div>
        <div onClick={accessorie}>Vehicles</div>
        <div onClick={vehicle}>Accessories</div>
        <div onClick={fashion}>Fashion</div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex space-x-16 p-4 mt-10">
        <div className=" w-64  bg-green-500">
          {data?.categories[filter]?.subCategories?.map((launch) => (
            <div key={launch.name}>{launch.name}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 p-10 font text-2xl  bg-green-500 ">
          {" "}
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
            {data?.categories[filter]?.products?.map((products) => (
              <div className="" key={products.name}>
                <div className="  bg-white rounded">
                  <div>{products?.name}</div>
                  <div>{products?.price}</div>
                  <div>
                    <img src={products?.images?.url} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

So, I can display the product `name` but not the product image `url`.

What can I do to display product image `url` along with it's product `name`?

Thanks

Comment: what is the `filter` here `data?.categories[filter]` ?

Comment: It's just a number value to display specific array of data, could you spot my mistake to display `images.url`. Thanks

Comment: `products.images` is an array. Arrays don’t have a `url` property.

Comment: @rayhatfield What about this? `"images": [
            {
              "__typename": "ProductImage",
              "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/511dBXGmAtL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
            },`

Comment: That would be `products.images[0].url`.

Answer (score 1):

> Images itself is an array of objects, so its required to map over it again

```
<div>
  {products?.images.map((img) => <img src={img.url} />)}
</div>
```

> If you want to show only just one image and that too the first one then we can do it as per @ray comment

```
<div>
  <img src={products?.images[0]?.url} />
</div>
```

Comment: This just displays all Images. I need each images mapped with @Codenewbie it's own product `name`. What your answer does is, it displays all available images inside each product `name` . Can you make make a single product `name` to have it's own product `image`? Thanks

Comment: But all those images are same for single product ?? check answer is that is the one expected  @TeshAych?

Answer (score 1):

Images is an array containing multiple images. You'll need to a secondary map over the array to access the URL on each object.

```
{data?.categories[filter]?.products?.map((products) => (
              <div className="" key={products.name}>
                <div className="  bg-white rounded">
                  <div>{products?.name}</div>
                  <div>{products?.price}</div>
                  <div>
                    {products.images.map((img) =>
                       <img src={img.url} />
                      )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
```

Comment: This just displays all Images. I need each images mapped with it's own product `name`. What your answer does is, it displays all available images inside each product `name` . Can you make make a single product `name` to have it's own product `image`? Thanks

Comment: Each product has its own array, implying there are multiple images for each product. If you only want one image, then you need to choose which one you want and display only that one. Or, if the images aren't correct for the product, there's an issue with your data.